# compile class with another class dependency

Tags: java, groovy

I have this structure in my folder

```
SupportUtils.groovy
Main.java
groovy-all-2.4.6.jar
```

I compile `groovy` file with command `groovyc SupportUtils.groovy` and get several `.class` files.

Now I want to compile `Main.java` file. I run this command

```
javac -cp groovy-all-2.4.6.jar Main.java
```

but I get error

```
Main.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
            List<String> list = SupportUtils.readFile("file.txt");
                                ^
 symbol:   variable SupportUtils
 location: class Main
```

meaning that it cannot find `SupportUtils` class. I do not have any package declarations in either `Main.java` or `SupportUtils.groovy`.

So how I should compile my `Main.java` class in that case?

Comment: Have you tried adding the ```.class``` files to your class path? Maybe the SupportUtils are not in the jar.

Comment: I thought it would be able to find it in the same folder. I guessed wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your classes from groovy are just dumped into the current folder, you probably need to add the current folder to the classpath

```
javac -cp .:groovy-all-2.4.6.jar Main.java
```

That's assuming you're on Linux or osx (you don't say)

The way you're doing things isn't a very nice way of doing things though

Using a build tool like gradle will help organise your code, and make your build reproducible, incase someone else needs to build the code, or some form of continuous deployment tool is being used

Comment: Why do I need `gradle` in order to compile pair of test classes with 5-10 lines of code? I am not creating any kind of project in that case.

Comment: Settings up Gradle would take a couple of minutes and saved you from experiencing this problem; surely that alone would make it worth it?

Comment: I use only `cmd` for now and see no reason to create the whole project structure just for that. I experienced that issue exactly due to the reason I never tried seriously to compile anything from console.

Comment: @user1432980 `gradle init --type groovy-library --test-framework spock`

Comment: @tim_yates, I know about it (though it adds spock even without parameter `--test-framework`) but in my case I do not think there is a need in doing that.